# Is it obligatory to have a .pgpass file when using psycopg2 on Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I have a Python3 program which uses `psycopg2` to connect to PostgreSQL databases. I was said that there is not any option in this library to ask for a password through a prompt. So my question is:

Do you have to have a `.pgpass` file (with the respective lines written) to do the connections to PostgreSQL through `psycopg2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way built into the library. There are numerious ways not built into the library. See, for example,  [getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html).

Basically, prompting for a password in a portable way is outside the scope of `psycopg2`. They could maybe mimic `getpass` on the commandline, but that's silly since you can just use that library. And they certainly aren't going to foster a windowing kit on you for a GUI. Basically, they assume that if you need to prompt a user for a password, you'll provide your own method of doing so.